# Recommended approach for loading CouchDB design documents in Python?

Tags: python, couchdb

I'm very new to couch, but I'm trying to use it on a new Python project, and I'd like to use python to write the design documents (views), also. I've already configured Couch to use the couchpy view server, and I can confirm this works by entering some simple map/reduce functions into Futon.

*Are there any official recommendations on how to load/synchronize design documents when using Python's couchdb module?*

I understand that I can post design documents to "install" them into Couch, but my question is really around best practices. I need some kind of strategy for deploying, both in development environments and in production environments. My intuition is to create a directory and store all of my design documents there, then write some kind of sync script that will upload each one into couch (probably just blindly overwriting what's already there). *Is this a good idea?*

The documentation for "[Writing views in Python](http://packages.python.org/CouchDB/views.html)" is 5 sentences, and really just explains how to install couchpy. On the [project's google code site](http://code.google.com/p/couchdb-python/), there is mention of a couchdb.design module that sounds like it might help, but there's no documentation (that I can find). The source code for that module indicates that it does most of what I'm interested in, but it stops short of actually loading files. I think I should do some kind of module discovery, but I've heard that's non-Pythonic. Advice?

Edit:

In particular, the idea of storing my map/reduce functions inside string literals seems *completely hacky*. I'd like to write real python code, in a real module, in a real package, with real unit tests. Periodically, I'd like to synchronize my "couch views" package with a couchdb instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach that seems reasonable. First, I subclass couchdb.design.ViewDefinition. (Comments and pydocs removed for brevity.)

```
import couchdb.design
import inflection

DESIGN_NAME="version"

class CurrentVersion(couchdb.design.ViewDefinition):
    def __init__(self):

        map_fun = self.__class__.map

        if hasattr(self.__class__, "reduce"):
            reduce_fun = self.__class__.reduce
        else:
            reduce_fun = None

        super_args = (DESIGN_NAME,
                      inflection.underscore(self.__class__.__name__),
                      map_fun,
                      reduce_fun,
                      'python')

        super(CurrentVersion, self).__init__(*super_args)

    @staticmethod
    def map(doc):
        if 'version_key' in doc and 'created_ts' in doc:
            yield (doc['version_key'], [doc['_id'], doc['created_ts']])

    @staticmethod
    def reduce(keys, values, rereduce):
        max_index = 0

        for index, value in enumerate(values):
            if value[1] > values[max_index][1]:
                max_index = index

        return values[max_index]
```

Now, if I want to synchronize:

```
import couchdb.design
from couchview.version import CurrentVersion

db = get_couch_db() # omitted for brevity
couchdb.design.ViewDefinition.sync_many(db, [CurrentVersion()], remove_missing=True)
```

The benefits of this approach are:

1. Organization. All designs/views exist as modules/classes (respectively) located in a single package.
2. Real code. My text editor will highlight syntax. I can write unit tests against my map/reduce functions.

The ViewDefinition subclass can also be used for querying.

```
current_version_view = couchview.version.CurrentVersion()
result = current_version_view(self.db, key=version_key)
```

It's still not ready for production, but I think this is a big step closer compared to storing map/reduce functions inside string literals.

Edit: I eventually wrote a couple blog posts on this topic, since I couldn't find any other sources of advice:

- http://markhaase.com/2012/06/23/couchdb-views-in-python/
- http://markhaase.com/2012/07/01/unit-tests-for-python-couchdb-views/