# How can I synchronize views from python couchdb to my design docs using a ViewField of the Document Mapping classes?

Tags: python, couchdb, couchdb-python

I'm trying to use the Document mapping classs for the python couchdb lib
but I am finding the docs extremely inadequate

It includes a few lines of code on how to define a view on the Document subclass your using
but these are not synced with the COuchDB design docs.
I have tried writing the same views with the same code in the CouchDB design doc ( through Futon ) and in my python classes but this doesn't synchronize them.
I am able to get the views working in other libraries such as couch query
so its not the views themselves that are the problem
They work in JavaScript or Python
unforntunately I have committed to using the DOcument subclasses to include functionality that I want associated with my Document subclasses. I have found other good info on how to synchronize the views to CouchDB using the a straight Doc class without the mapping provided by the variuos field types here:
[Recommended approach for loading CouchDB design documents in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707814/recommended-approach-for-loading-couchdb-design-documents-in-python/10723613#10723613)
and here:
http://markhaase.com/2012/06/23/couchdb-views-in-python/
 but their is no documentation to be found on how this works using the mapping Document subclasses

I've used both forms described in the docs:

```
class Person(Document):
...     name = TextField()
...     age = IntegerField()
...     by_name = ViewField('people', '''\
...         function(doc) {
...             emit(doc.name, doc);
...         }''')
```

and:

```
class Person(Document):
...     name = TextField()
...     age = IntegerField()
...
...     @ViewField.define('people')
...     def by_name(doc):
...         yield doc['name'], doc ( for Python views ):
```

when the view is called it fails and its immediately obviuos why:
inspecting Futon shows the view is not in the design doc

If I create the view in the design doc through various means the view works but its not wired to my Document subclass ( the Person class in this example ).

I guess I was hoping this was going to feel a lot more relaxing
I've though of using couch-query for get the view results and try to gerrymander those objects into my DOcument subclass in the seperate library python couchdb
but this seems extremely desperate and dirty and I'm not even able to access the dictionary information in couch-query easily anyhow.
Let me know if anybody can tell me how this is supposed to work. I suspect there's an easy answer that is simply completely missing in the docs or otherwise nobody would have written the Document mapping functionality

Answer (score 0):

Anybody wanting to address these questions for the benefit of the community are welcome,
My answer is to move on to the CouchDBKit library and I suggest others do as well.
There's a lot of similarity with couchdb-python including the mapping functionality I wanted, but its a much better maintained library with descent docs, a simple powerful architecture, some nice integrations with Django and FormAlchemy and some bonuses on top like going between CouchDB and the filesystem, and a database change listener. For my puroses there is nothing couchdb-python has that couchdbkit doesn't.